# Shiny Server cannot use RODBC to connect to DB2 but RStudio can in a Docker Container

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny-server, rodbc, unixodbc

I am working on deploying a shiny application in a Docker container onto Bluemix. I am using the rocker/shiny Docker image (https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/shiny/) as my initial starting point. I have installed unixODBC-dev, RODBC, ibm data server driver package, the ibmdbR library for R, and all needed dependencies. My only problem is that when I try to access the shiny app from a web browser it fails to execute, the error is:

```
Warning in odbcDriverConnect("DSN=BLUDB",  :
[RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 0, message [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/root/db2_cli_odbc_driver/dsdriver/odbc_cli_driver/linuxamd64/clidriver/lib/libdb2o.so' : file not found
Warning in odbcDriverConnect("DSN=BLUDB;  :
ODBC connection failed
Error in idaInit(con) : con is not an open connection, please use idaConnect() to create an open connection to the data base.
```

Initially I had this same problem whenever I would try to use isql to connect to the database or try to connect from RStudio, I used ldd on that library file and found what was missing and that fixed making connections from the command line and RStudio, however my Shiny-Server still gives me the same error, is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the problem myself, turns out the libraries were not accessible by the shiny-server which was running as a service. I moved the db2 odbc drivers over to /usr/local/lib to make it accessible, I also ran the "ldd" command on the library mentioned in the error message and found that I had to install libxml2 as well. After doing that I simply changed my odbcinst.ini file at /etc to reference the new location of the db2 library and now it all works! Hopefully anyone else trying to deploy Shiny Apps that rely on connecting to a DB2 database will find this useful.